# Show barcode value in Barcode Scanner immediately after camera capture?

Tags: android, android-intent, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am trying to display the scanned barcode value immediately after scanning, where the Barcode Scanner app displays, such that it might display:

```
Found Plain Text - "Insert Barcodevalue here".
```

Is it possible to do this via intent setting?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, but, I can make this change for the next version so that it always shows the contents.